# How do I troubleshoot a breaking script?

Tags: php, memory

I am using plupload multi file uploader on part of my form. I am able to upload all my photos to the server. PLupload basically uploads the files, then places hidden fields on the form, from what I understand. When I submit the form so as to create records the script takes a while to run, and finally outputs. The strange thing is that it reaches some sort of limit at around 47 records, and then stops with the HTML output, not showing if anything happens with the rest of the pictures, and not displaying my footer.

I need some help troubleshooting why my script is failing. I have echoed out `memory_get_peak_usage` at various points in my loop and memory seems to be stable throughout. I have also used `imagedestroy()` to clear out some of the image resources that I have created to free up any memory. I also added `set_time_limit(10);` in my loop in the case that it was timing out.

I have also turned on error_reporting.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I don't get any errors, just less than expected output. I have checked the Apache logs, and there is nothing in there.
Does anyone have input on techniques for troubleshooting this further?

Comment: Are you hosting this yourself?  Is ini_set() [a disabled function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) in your php configuration?  Check [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to tell whether ini_set() is enabled or disabled.

Comment: @jedwards - I am hosting with media temple. I checked with phpinfo and don't see ini_set() at all. However, I checked for 'display_errors' and it is on. I checked 'disable_functions' and that has no value.

Comment: disable_functions having no value means that you should be able to set display_errors anywhere and as long as your script doesn't have fatal (parse) errors, you should be fine.  I'd check the apache logs next as suggested.

Comment: Not entirely sure if php would log it, so check `/var/log/messages` for filesystem full messages.

Answer (score 1):

Apache errors should be in http-errors.log
In linux this file is on var/log/http-error.log
In windows I don't know, do not care either.

Comment: Thanks, but checked that out this morning. Nothing helpful there.

Comment: @john cartwright - not sure where the php error logs are going. bear with me, I'm pretty green. I checked in php.ini for error_log, it wasn't in there. I checked phpinfo() and there was no value for it. I added 

; Error log
error_log = /logs/error_log

to php.ini. Will that do it for me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is applicable on this specific case but what I do is that I usually create a wrapper file "debug.php" which contains your two lines and then includes the script which is not working, i.e.

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('my_script.php');
```

This usually helps detecting errors otherwise not shown for different reasons.

Comment: My form is setup to post to itself. If I were to change it to post back to "debug.php" would everything still work? I guess there's one way to find out...

Comment: I didn't need to change the reference. Everything worked fine with 1 file. I am uploading 55 now to see if anything is output at the 47 mark.

Comment: Have turned on PHP logging (I think) as noted above, and am running this inside this debug wrapper. Oddly, I've been limited at 47 records all day, so I've been doing test cases with 50 (not 55, whoops). Anyway it worked fine with 50 this time, so I have bumped up to 70. We'll see...

Comment: Unfortunately that did not provide any different output. Thanks for your input. I will surely be able to use that technique another time.